# How to remove 4 byte utf-8 characters in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding, utf8mb4

Since MySQL's utf8 doesn't support 4 byte characters, I'm looking for a way to detect and eliminate any 4 byte utf8 characters from a string in Ruby.  I understand that I can update my table to use utf8m4 but for a couple reasons that's not possible or the desired solution.

Simply encoding the string to ASCII will remove these characters but will also remove all other non-ASCII characters, which is not good.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The following seems to work for me in Ruby 1.9.3:

```
input.each_char.select{|c| c.bytes.count < 4 }.join('')
```

For example:

```
input = "hello \xF0\xA9\xB6\x98 world"                  # includes U+29D98
input.each_char.select{|c| c.bytes.count < 4 }.join('') # 'hello  world'
```

Comment: Thanks!  Seems obvious now that you've suggested it.  I was so deep in thinking about encodings, I didn't think to simply look at the byte count of each character.

Comment: How is the performance of this with a long string? 5000+ chars?

Comment: thank you thank you thank you ... not personally worried about performance, for the moment I'm happy to have a working solution

Comment: That is not efficient at all, is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Another option (tested in ruby 2.7) is to use a regular expression with gsub:

```
input = "hello \xF0\xA9\xB6\x98 world"    # includes U+29D98
input.gsub(/[\u{10000}-\u{10FFFF}]/, "?") # 'hello ? world'
```