# "Incorrect string value" when trying to insert UTF-8 into MySQL from Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, validation, utf-8, utf8mb4

While debugging my Rails App I found the following messages in the log file:

```
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms (ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x89 u...' for column 'description' at row 1: INSERT INTO `course` (`title`, `description`) VALUES ('sometitle', '<p>Description containing  and stuff</p>')
```

This seems to stem from my database being MySQL with not-quite-utf-8:

```
CREATE TABLE `course` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2080 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

According to [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc) CHARSET=utf8 is only capable of handling 3 byte characters, not 4 byte characters.

The Emoticon    needs four bytes - see \xF0\x9F\x98\x89 in the log file.

I am wary of converting the whole database. I would rather forbid the use of emoticons and other 4 byte characters - they are really not necessary on my site.

What is the best way to do this in Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the [regular expressions from these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487697/how-to-remove-4-byte-utf-8-characters-in-ruby) I implemented a validator:

```
# file /lib/three_byte_validator.rb
# forbid characters that use more than three byte
class ThreeByteValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if value =~ /[\u{10000}-\u{10FFFF}]/
      record.errors.add attribute, (options[:message] || 'Keine Emoticons, keine UTF-8 Zeichen mit 4 Byte')
    end
  end
end
```

Now I can use this validator on the model that first had the problem:

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, length: { in: 3..100 }, three_byte: true
  validates :description, length: { minimum: 50 }, three_byte: true
```

and also on other models:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :firstname, :lastname, :country, :city, :address, three_byte: true
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the Winking Face (and most other Emoji) needs `utf8mb4` instead of `utf8`.

Comment: yes, thank you! but as I said: I am wary of converting the whole database. it's in production, there is a lot of data. I'd rather not change something so fundamental.